# To determine whether given set is closed or bounded

Tags: real-analysis

Given that $S=\{x\in \Bbb R:x^{6}-x^{5}\le100\}$ and $T=\{x^{2}-2x:x\in(0,\infty)\}$.The Question was to find whether set $S\cap T$ is closed or bounded or both or neither?I try to find both the sets but got no idea about $S$ but I got  $T=[-1,\infty)$ but not sure.Please give me some hint for $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Your $T$ looks correct. It isn't very easy to find $S$ explicitly. But I would say it *is* rather easy to see what form it must have, and that's all you need: it is of the form $[-a, b]$ where $2<a<b<3$.

Comment: oh, I had a mistake sorry, you are right, look at my answer, $3$ is way higher than what $b$ can really be

Answer (score 0):

First let's observe and see that $x^6-x^5=x^5(x-1)$.

We need to keep in mind that $\sqrt[5]{100}>1$, so we know that $\sqrt[5]{100}^5(\sqrt[5]{100}-1)>100$. Another thing to keep in mind is that when we look at negative values we have negative times negative so we get positive, so we know that $-\sqrt[5]{100}^5(-\sqrt[5]{100}-1)>100$

From this we get that $S\subset (-\sqrt[5]{100},\sqrt[5]{100})$

With clever observation we also can find that $\sqrt[5]{\frac{100}3}>2$ which implies that $-\sqrt[5]{\frac{100}3}^5(-\sqrt[5]{\frac{100}3}-1)>100$, so we can reduce the form to get that $S\subset (-\sqrt[5]{\frac{100}3},\sqrt[5]{100})$ and we also know that there is some value, one positive and one negative,
(because of continuity) that $x^5(x-1)=100$ so we get $S\subset_{closed} (-\sqrt[5]{\frac{100}3},\sqrt[5]{100})$

I am not sure if there is an easy way to solve it but this is the most reduce form I can think of without trial and error

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: I believe you mean to say $(\sqrt[5]{100})^5 (\sqrt[5]{100} -1) > 100$.

Comment: @eepperly16 yes, sorry